# Why windows azure does not support SSIS?

Tags: ssis, azure, azure-sql-database

Is there any specific reason why we can't use SSIS in windows azure ?

Answer (score 6):

Windows Azure only supports a [subset of features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394115.aspx) of SQL Server via the [Azure SQL components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336279.aspx). SSIS can only be used locally (***on-premise*** in cloud terminology) for the time being, but SSIS will likely be ported eventually.

As an alternative - you could use SSIS locally and combine it with [SQL Data Sync](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-data-sync-overview.aspx) if you intend on changing (*insert/update/delete*) any of the data via SSIS (*versus just exporting - selects*).

Windows Azure is still maturing - it has only [been RTM since 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Services_Platform). Each existing component must be ported over to the new Azure structure which takes extensive re-developing.

Comment: Was about to answer but then noticed that you already mentioned the Data Sync approach :-).

Answer (score 1):

SSIS isn't currently supported on SQL Azure, I'm not sure what is the background for the question, but I don't know if there is a need to seek a specific reason - there are still many technologies that are not (yet) supported on Azure but Microsoft is increasingly introducing more capabilities.

For example- SSRS was not available on Azure initially, but is now in CTP, and will be RTM in the near future; I don't think it's a question of if, but rather a question of when (but I'm sorry, I don't have an answer for that one)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are all correct. In addition, another option to you is to actually RUN your SSIS packages on your on-premise server but to hit a remote SQL Azure server. Depending on what all you're doing, this is certainly possible.

Check out [this article](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Migrating_Data_to_SQL_Azure_Using_SSIS) on migrating data from on-premise to SQL Azure using SSIS. It's not exactly an answer to what you're asking, but it provides a good example of integrating SSIS with Azure.