# Running SSIS packages in Azure

Tags: azure, ssis

I am looking to move my web app to the cloud. The web app uses SQL to store data which the data comes from about 10 SSIS packages.The packages themselves require less than a 5 hours to run all combined in a day and the amount of data they send is very small less then 5MB in a day.

So the Free Web Azure solution seems to fit the need for data storage and running the site but does it allow one to schedule SQL Agent jobs and execute SSIS packages
I looked at the VM AZURE solution but it is pricey for my pockets at the moment.
Alternatively can someone direct me to a hosting service that can meet my requirements and still be cheap?

Comment: Great first post, and welcome to SO!  Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455446/why-windows-azure-does-not-support-ssis) for an answer to your question (SSIS packages are not supported by Azure).

Comment: if you'd like to open other questions to address your packages taking 5  hours to load 5mb  of data, I suspect wr can be of assistance

Answer (score 7):

By Free Web Azure, if you mean Azure Websites, then it is not possible.

Even Azure SQL database doesn't support SQL Agent as well as SSIS.

Your best bet is to use Azure IaaS VM as you already mentioned ( http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/install-sql-server/ )

Answer (score 0):

dualcorp has developed a dll to use ssis online. This name is essis a trial can be find on nuget and the llcence on https://www.dualcorp.fr/Product.aspx?id=jKIoPSeLL9plO8H1ZBAePg==

Answer (score 0):

If you use Amazon Web Services, even the free version of the service allows you to create Ms SQL Server databases in the cloud that have the SSIS catalog and the Server Agent available

Comment: In the meantime there is complete setup for SSIS catalogs, so SSIS packages can be deployed there in the same manner as on a local instance.

Comment: Also Azure SQL Server Managed instance is comming that will allow you to have a full blown SQL Server in the cloud with SSIS support.