# Azure and SSIS Packages

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

I have been scratching my head over how I will deploy a data warehouse ecosystem on Microsoft Azure. From my understanding, none of the current SQL offerings allow you to run SSIS packages (SQL Azure, SQL Data Warehouse).

It looks like I'd need to spin up a VM to be able to execute SSIS packages using the Integration Service that comes with the SQL installation media.

But this is where it gets expensive and cumbersome. From what I see, my ecosystem would need to be:

1) A SQL Azure Data Warehouse to store my facts and dimensions

2) A SQL Azure standard SQL Database to store my staging area

3) A VM with Integration Services installed to execute my SSIS packages

With this, I'm paying for a Azure Data Warehouse, a SQL Azure database, a VM AND I'm also having to purchase an on-prem edition of SQL Server in order to license the SSIS exec.

Is there an easier, more cost effective way? I can't see much of an advantage here, I suppose I could install SQL Server on the VM and use that instead of SQL Azure for staging, but then I might as well just not bother with Azure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running SSIS packages in Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374156/running-ssis-packages-in-azure)

Comment: I noticed that, however it's from 2013 and I was hoping that there is an alternative now.

Comment: There is an alternative now - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provision an Integration Runtime within Azure Data Factory to hold your Azure based SSIS package

[Deploy SSIS to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure)

[Lift and Shift SSIS to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-lift-shift-ssis-packages-overview?view=sql-server-2017)