# Can I use SSIS on free Azure

Tags: azure, ssis

Can I use SSIS on free Azure? I have a package that does a simple ETL function from an excel sheet to a Sql database that I want to be able to run on the cloud.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running SSIS packages in Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374156/running-ssis-packages-in-azure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run SSIS in your on-premises database and connect to azure. Just give it the correct connection string and it should work.