# Tool for Azure SQL data warehouse sync

Tags: sql, azure, sql-data-warehouse

I'm looking to automatically synchronise the data from an Azure SQL database to an Azure SQL data warehouse. It probably only needs to be inserting rather than updating, it will involve 25-35 tables and several million records in a few of the tables. (later on once the data is synced we may delete synced records from the source.)

Can anyone recommend some tools or approaches that could do this, suiting most of the requirements above?

I've looked at Data factory but that does not seem suited to incremental loads

Answer (score 0):

The on-premise way would be a [SQL Server Integration Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-sql-server-with-integration-services) project. This would allow you to copy data both incrementally and in bulk, with any required transformations. Also see [data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/data-flow) documentation.

As noted by Peter Bons, this is not directly supported on the Azure platform.
If you have a license for SQL server available, you can set up an Azure VM with SQL Server and SSIS.

For further discussion see

- [Why windows azure does not support SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455446/why-windows-azure-does-not-support-ssis)
- [Running SSIS packages in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374156/running-ssis-packages-in-azure)

One note in those other questions is:

> If you use Amazon Web Services, even the free version of the service
>   allows you to create Ms SQL Server databases in the cloud that have
>   the SSIS catalog and the Server Agent available

I can't vouch for that, but if a full SQL Server license is not something that is available, you might want to try it.

Comment: SSIS is not available on Azure as a service. You will need to create a VM for that and buy a Sql Server Licence. So it would be a very expensive option

Comment: @PeterBons - apologies, you are correct. I have edited the answer.