# Build and Deploy SSIS packages using VSTS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I created the simple SSIS project in VS2015 with SQL Server 2012 as a targeted server, it will worked in local machine successfully without any issues. After that I have created the build definition and release definition by following this [link](https://github.com/ToxicGlobe/VSTS-SSIS-Extension/wiki/How-to-Setup-build).

For this project build will be success. But release definition failed with this **“##[error]Task_InternalError Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s):** Failed to connect to server DNS name label.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com,1433" error message in Deploy SSIS step like this below figure.
[image]
But here I used the virtual machine with SQL server2012 for hosting the SSIS package.

Can you please tell me how to resolve the above issue as soon as possible and also tell me is there any alternative way to deploy the SSIS project using VSTS?

Comment: Do you [open 1433 ports to a virtual machine with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal)? Do you configure TCP/IP for SQL Server? [Connect to Windows Azure Virtual Machine Using SSMS](https://logicalread.com/connect-windows-azure-vm-using-ssms-tl01/#.WajNFMgjGM8)? Can you connect to that SQL Server from your local machine?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect the SQL Server inside virtual machine from my local machine.

Comment: Set system.debug to true, then queue build and post the detail log here (can share it on the OneDrive).

Comment: Logs available in this link https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CvWv57X_rRyhkH4xD

Comment: I followed this link https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TG.VSTS-SSIS to setup release definition for SSIS package, but I did not understand what are project parameters are given. So, can you please tell me which project parameters are given in the Deploy SSIS step in release definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/ToxicGlobe/VSTS-SSIS-Extension/blob/master/DeploySSISTask/DeploySSISTask.ps1), the connection uses windows authentication (Integrated Security=SSPI), but the Hosted agent uses service account, so it can’t connect to the server.

You can refer to the source code to build the PowerShell script to deploy SSIS project and the project name is the name of the SSIS project. (Using SQL Server authentication: User ID=XXX;Password=XXX)

Another article with the code about deploying SSIS: [Deployment Automation for SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/deployment-automation-for-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/)

Comment: Thanks, I already configured private agent running with my VSTS for deploying SSIS package.

Comment: @pradeep The SQL Server is in Azure, so you need to use SQL Server authentication.

Comment: @pradeep Do you connect to that SQL Server with SQL Server authentication from your local machine?

Comment: No I used windows authentication to connect SQL Server from my local machine.

Comment: What's the result If you are using Private build agent (Running with your account)?

Comment: Yes, its working fine using private build agent but currently I used local SQL Server not an Azure SQL Server and Database.

Comment: Could you connect to the Azure SQL Server with your account?

Comment: Since you can connect to Azure SQL Server with your account, just need to make sure the private build agent is running with your account, then the windows authentication is ok.

Comment: when I connect to azure SQL database, it doesn't show the Integration Services Catalogs folder for creating Catalog inside it.

Comment: By seeing this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455446/why-windows-azure-does-not-support-ssis Azure SQL Database doesn't support for SSIS package deployment.

Comment: @Pradeep did you managed to do the deployment ?Stack on the same issue