# Deploy SSIS task in VSTS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-devops

I'm trying to use a "Deploy SSIS" task in VSTS. I get this error:

Task_InternalError Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to connect to server xyz

It is asking for the following information below. How do I go about finding the information below needed for this task? The path to the .ispac file is easy since it is uploaded. I also think the name of the server is correct.

-Display name

-Path to .ispac file

-Name of the SSIS project in the .ispac file

-Name of the SQL Server hosting the SSIS catalog database

-Name of the SSIS catalog

-Name of the SSIS catalog folder

-Description of the SSIS catalog folder

Edit: 
(detailed error log)

2017-09-20T12:55:05.6438379Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_PROJECTFILEPATH: 'd:\a\3\s\HR Data.ispac'

2017-09-20T12:55:05.6468345Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_PROJECTNAME: 'xyz'

2017-09-20T12:55:05.6488487Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_SERVERNAME: 'xyz'

2017-09-20T12:55:05.6538355Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_CATALOGNAME: 'xyz'

2017-09-20T12:55:05.6558353Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_FOLDERNAME: 'xyz'

2017-09-20T12:55:05.6568351Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_FOLDERDESCRIPTION (empty)

2017-09-20T12:55:05.6618490Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_PROJECTPARAMETERS (empty)

2017-09-20T12:55:05.6628342Z SQL Connection String: Data Source=xyz;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;

2017-09-20T12:55:05.6638360Z Project file path: d:\a\3\s\xyz.ispac

2017-09-20T12:55:22.8057049Z ##[debug]Leaving D:\a_tasks\DeploySsis_582498ad-81d6-48b7-b9bc-fd0e5dec2e2b\0.1.0\DeploySSISTask.ps1.

2017-09-20T12:55:22.8388650Z ##[debug]Caught exception from task script.

2017-09-20T12:55:22.8418679Z ##[debug]Error record:

2017-09-20T12:55:22.8948708Z ##[debug]D:\a_tasks\DeploySsis_582498ad-81d6-48b7-b9bc-fd0e5dec2e2b\0.1.0\DeploySSISTask.ps1 : Task_InternalError Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to connect to server xyz."

2017-09-20T12:55:22.8968708Z ##[debug]At line:1 char:1

2017-09-20T12:55:22.8978718Z ##[debug]+ . 'd:\a_tasks\DeploySsis_582498ad-81d6-48b7-b9bc-fd0e5dec2e2b\0.1.0\ ...

2017-09-20T12:55:22.8988697Z ##[debug]+

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2017-09-20T12:55:22.8998697Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9008861Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,DeploySSISTask.ps1

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9018704Z ##[debug]

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9048688Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9078699Z ##[debug]at , 
D:\a_tasks\DeploySsis_582498ad-81d6-48b7-b9bc-fd0e5dec2e2b\0.1.0\DeploySSISTask.ps1: line 97

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9098691Z ##[debug]at , : line 1

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9108747Z ##[debug]at , : line 22

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9118883Z ##[debug]at , : line 18

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9128882Z ##[debug]at , : line 1

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9148698Z ##[debug]Exception:

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9188799Z ##[debug]Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Task_InternalError Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to connect to server xyz."

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9478706Z ##[error]Task_InternalError Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to connect to server xyz."

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9478706Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Task_InternalError Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to connect to server xyz."

2017-09-20T12:55:22.9508700Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]

Comment: Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and check whether there is detail error message. Do you use Hosted agent? Does xyz server can be accessed from build agent?

Comment: Yes Hosted agent: Hosted VS2017. I think that's the problem I think. The catalog data I just gave as a wild guess since I don't have access to it. Will try to get permissions to see it and I expect it will be fixed.

Comment: Do you solve this issue with private build agent or custom PowerShell script?

Comment: I'm still working on getting either one of these to work. I will follow up with which one worked or worked better. Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to post the result here after trying them.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Deploy SSIS task, it connects to the server with windows authentication (Integrated Security=SSPI), but the Hosted agent uses service account that can’t connect to the server.

You can set up a private build agent (running as your account) and queue build with that build agent, or you can refer to the [source code](https://github.com/ToxicGlobe/VSTS-SSIS-Extension/tree/master/DeploySSISTask) to build the PowerShell script to deploy SSIS project with SQL Server authentication (User ID=XXX; Password=XX)

A related thread: [Build and Deploy SSIS packages using VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978672/build-and-deploy-ssis-packages-using-vsts)